# How to get location/url of image from CollectionFS (Meteor)

Tags: node.js, image, mongodb, meteor, collectionfs

I am trying to get the file location/url from a image I have just inserted. I have tried to use the path  + objectID but the image is not present. I am trying to store the image url in another collection. So I can load that collection into my template and use the iamge url as img source.

```
var ShopsImageFS = new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
  path: "~/shop/images/"
});

ShopsImages = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [ShopsImageFS],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 3145728,
    allow: {
  contentTypes: ['image/*'],
  extensions: ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG']
}}
});

Template.newshop.events({
  "change .image": function(event, template){
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      ShopsImages.insert(file, function (err, fileObj){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {

          Session.set("imageURL", "~/shop/images/" + fileObj);
          // not working
        }
      })
    })
  },

var imageURL = Session.get('imageURL');

Meteor.call("addShop", date, name, description, imageURL, address, postcode, city, country, latitude, longitude);
```

server.js

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.methods({
      addShop:function (date, name, description, imageURL ,address, postcode, city, country, latitude, longitude) {

          Shops.insert({date:date, name:name, description:description, imageURL:imageURL, address:address, postcode:postcode, city:city, country:country,  latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude});
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      {{#each shopList}}
        {{>shopCard}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>

<template name="shopCard">

<a style="text-decoration: none;" href="{{ pathFor route='shop.show' name=name _id=_id }}">
  <div id="shopCardItem">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <img id="shopImage" src="{{imageURL}}" alt="{{name}}"/>

    <div id="shopContent">
      <h1>{{name}}</h1>
      <p>{{city}}</p>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>

</a>

</template>
```

home.js

```
Template.home.helpers({
  shopList: function() {
    var search_query = Session.get('search_query');
    return Shops.find({name: { $regex: search_query + ".*", $options: 'i' }});

  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't that a typo in your code? Your param is "fileObj" and you're using it as "fileObje".

Comment: @dooart no its not. typo when I was submitting the question ;P. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is at `fileObj.url()`. If you have different stores you can get the url to different stores using `fileObj.url("storeName")`.

If you want to set an image src use a technique like so:

```
{{#each shopimage}}
    <img src="{{this.url store='images'}}">
{{/each}}
```

Where:

```
 shopimage : function () {
     return ShopImages.find();
 }
```

Comment: @tom12e where are you calling `fileObj.url()`?

Comment: inside ShopsImages.insert()

Comment: @tom12e I just finished some personal testing on this subject. At the point of the callback is fired the file has successfully uploaded the file yet, you can check with `console.log(fileObj.isUploaded())` which will print `false`, thus your `fileObj.url() is null` . If you set a `Meteor.setTimeout( function () {
                                    console.log(fileObj.url());
                                }, 3000);` where you were calling `f`ileObj.url()` you will now see the `fileObj.url()` no longer returns null but an actual path.

Comment: @tom12e there is probably a much better way to get the path then from a `timeout` inside of the file insert callback. What are you trying to do exactly with the Session that you are setting?

Comment: going to try it! I am storing the session inside an other collection. So I can easly load it into an <img>.

Comment: I am already using #each, i've updated my question. (i've left some unnecessary code out)

Comment: @tom12e so the problem is really linking the two collections, ShopImages and Shops. What I would do is add a shopId key value pair to the ShopImages collection and then return `ShopImages.find({shopId : this._id})`

Comment: Nate, thanks man! great idea. I've applied it and it works like a charm! (: